# How to Clean Address Data in R or Excel?

Tags: r, regex, excel

I have a list of addresses that have unnecessary information.
I would like to remove string between first `,` and second `,` including commas.
for example: `527 TEST RD, APT 22, EDINBURG, TX`
I want to make it `527 TEST RD, EDINBURG, TX`

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Do you expect all data to have at least two commas, after street and city? i.e. remove the text between the first set of commas unless there are only two commas? Could you provide a sample data set as well?

Comment: Hi ErrorJordan, yes I do.

Comment: @poshan What version of Excel?  And please provide a more comprehensive sample data set, showing the potential variability and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `sub` to extract the data needed in two capture groups. 1st one is everything before 1st comma and 2nd one to extract after the second comma.

```
x <- "527 TEST RD, APT 22, EDINBURG, TX"
sub("(.*?,).*?,(.*)", "\\1\\2", x)
#[1] "527 TEST RD, EDINBURG, TX"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Excel**

Let's assume your data is in column A. In order to clean it according your request, you can use the following formula in column B:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)-1)&", "&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1))
```

First, we look at the position of the first comma using `FIND(",",A1,1)`

With the help oft the `LEFT` function, we can collect the string in front of the first comma.

Then we have to find the position of the second comma `FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,1)` (as you see, we need the position of the first comma in order to do that).

Now, we can use the `RIGHT` function, to get the text from the right side until the second comma.

I hope that helps you.